# Is it possible to hide offline printers?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, printer

May I ask if there is any way to hide offline printers?

The problem is that I have a laptop with a number of printers installed. These printers are physically resided in different locations. When I work in one place, only some printers are available. It turns out to be difficult to select the right printer from the long list.

Thank you in advance.

**The Question Illustrated**:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for windows 7, windows 8 might be similar.

In the *Devices and printers* window (first screenshot in your question), if you switch to details view, you could group devices by status.

Right click the column titles and choose `More...` and check *Status* in the list of details to show. Then click OK.

Back in the *Devices and printers* window, click on the downward looking triangle in the *Status* column (it's invisible unless you hover over the column title and normally shows on the right side of the name). It'll show you a list of possible statuses. Check all the ones you want to see and leave out the ones to hide. This is the filter list. Or you could instead group them. Play with that or with the `Group by` and `Sort by` options in the `View` menu.

[image: filter printers window]

After choosing the filters, you can go back to big icons view.

In the *print* dialog box (second screenshot) in the list that shows you a list of printers to choose from, right click the background (i.e. not in one of the printers) and you get a similar menu to the `View` menu mentioned above. You can also switch to detail view and can also use a filter in the columns as for the printers list above.

[image: How to filter printers]